# How do I make to make picture solarized like example

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photo-editing, shadows, highlights

I'm now self-learning PTS and I want to edit my photo into the color or maybe into this style like this picture. Anyone knows? Please show me how. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a Curves adjustment to create a solarization effect.

[image]

Then you could use a Hue and Saturation adjustment to increase the saturation and alter the colours as required.

[image]

Comment: This is the way!

Answer (score 0):

This effect could be achieved with a gradient map:

Pick an image:
[image: Original Image]

---

Add a gradient map layer and add your colors. Use the stops between the colors to decide where you want your colors to end up or how posterized you want it to look:

[image: Add a Gradient Map Layer]

---

You get something like this. I'm sure you could do better

[image: After]

Comment: YOu can do thi with a gradient map, but it does diminish the available resoltion of the mage. The alternative is to use curves, which doe snot do this and thus has a tendency to produce better results And less likely to noise very small color variations.